# VS + Team Foundation Server Connection Issue

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

My TFS has a internal and a external address. How can I make VS check both before declaring it "offline"/"unreachable"?

Maybe connect a project to 2 servers?!?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible as of today. It tries to connect to a single instance of TFS address at a time.